# Laravel Eloquent - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get all of a users completed habits, although I'm getting a syntax issue when using eloquent?

What's going on here... syntax seems fine to me.

Query:

```
$completedHabits = Habit::query()
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->join('habit_goals', 'habits.id', '=', 'habit_goals.habit_id')
            ->whereHas('progressLogs', function($q) {
                $q
                    ->whereRaw('created_at >= SUBTIME(created_at, INTERVAL habit_goals.interval SECOND)')
                    ->select(\DB::raw('SUM(value) as valueCommited'))
                    ->havingRaw('valueCommited > habit_goals.value');
            })
            ->orderBy('habit_goals.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Full error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') having valueCommited > habit_goals.value) order by `habit_goals`.`created_at` ' at line 1

Comment: Syntax of the Eloquent may seem fine, but you should dump the real SQL query, and then it should be clear what is incorrect. Try changing `->get()` to `->toSql()` and then `dd($completedHabits);`. Or, if you're on Laravel 10.15+, the new `->toRawSql()`

Comment: Try this  ->havingRaw("\DB::raw('SUM(value)')  > habit_goals.value"), 
instead of ->havingRaw('valueCommited > habit_goals.value'), check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `FROM` and `GROUP BY` clauses are missing.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to solve that?